# Can I load hdf5 model from firebase storage?

Tags: python, firebase, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, hdf5

I use firebase as a database and storage and I want to run my model on the python and perform predict.

How can I load the model and run it on python?

How do I access a model stored in storage?

I tried to do:

```
# import firebase_admin
# from firebase_admin import credentials
# from firebase_admin import storage
#
# cred = credentials.Certificate('serviceAccountKey.json')
# firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
# 'storageBucket': 'gs://app.appspot.com.appspot.com'
# })

import pyrebase
config={
    "apiKey": "",
    "authDomain": "app.firebaseapp.com",
    "storageBucket":"app.appspot.com",
    "databaseURL":"https://app.firebaseio.com",
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "app"
    # "private_key_id": "633bcc74c30d50157a0aea2dd"
}

firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage=firebase.storage()
```

I checked that I am connected to storage and have the option to upload and download photos.

Then I copied the link to the model what firease storage

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import tensorflow as tf

MODEL_PATH = "gs://app.appspot.com/model.hdf5"

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(MODEL_PATH)
```

But it shows me errors and does not work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hoday\Documents\GitHub\SRD\storgesever.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyrebase
  File "C:\Users\hoday\venv\untitled\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyrebase import initialize_app
  File "C:\Users\hoday\venv\untitled\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\hoday\venv\untitled\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\hoday\venv\untitled\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "C:\Users\hoday\venv\untitled\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 172, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help me :)

Comment: "shows me errors and does not work" is too generic, you need to provide actual error messages and explain "does not work". If not you are leaving people to guess.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy You're right, I'm sorry, I added

Answer (score 0):

Use the Firebase client to download the model to the local destination and then load it from the local storage.

Comment: I have a client side -an app in java and a server side-a Python server,
The model is a very large file so I can not download it to the device and run it,
So I thought of loading it on the server but I can not access the model...

Comment: I mean to download it to the server where is the Python code, so it's on the server I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

That is generic questions you can create a project and access its database or drive try using GoogleDrive.

You can follow the guidelines from [Google Drive](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/google-drive-api-with-python-part-ii-connect-to-google-drive-and-search-for-file-7138422e0563) that is using Google Drive with project credentials access.

The question is about Google Cloud but it applied for Tensorflow or any file can be coinversion with the same idea.

**[ Sample ]:**

```
from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import client, file, tools

# define path variables
credentials_file_path = 'F:\\temp\\Python\\credentials\\credentials.json'
clientsecret_file_path = 'F:\\temp\\Python\\credentials\\client_secret_183167298301-pfhgtdf6k8r4918csmftemgk00ln8l4r.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'

# define API scope
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

# define store
store = file.Storage(credentials_file_path)
credentials = store.get()
# get access token
if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(clientsecret_file_path, SCOPE)
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    
# define API service
http = credentials.authorize(Http())
drive = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)   
    
# define a function to retrieve all files
def retrieve_all_files(api_service, filename_to_search):
    results = []
    page_token = None

    while True:
        try:
            param = {}

            if page_token:
                param['pageToken'] = page_token

            files = api_service.files().list(**param).execute()
# append the files from the current result page to our list
            results.extend(files.get('files'))
# Google Drive API shows our files in multiple pages when the number of files exceed 100
            page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')

            if not page_token:
                break

        except errors.HttpError as error:
            print(f'An error has occurred: {error}')
            break
# output the file metadata to console
    for file in results:
        if file.get('name') == filename_to_search:
            print(file)
            break

    return results, file
            
# call the function
filename_to_search = 'Christmas Plan'
all_files, search_file = retrieve_all_files(drive, filename_to_search)

print( all_files )
print( search_file )
```